# Translating a Gravity (a scripting language) call to a native C function call

Tags: c++, c, calling-convention, scripting-language, gravity-language

I am currently looking into implementing a cleaner way to call native C functions from the [Gravity](https://marcobambini.github.io/gravity/#/) scripting language.

So far, the most simplistic example would be this one:

```
int add(int lhs, int rhs) {
  return lhs + rhs;
}

static void gravity_wrap_add(
  gravity_vm* vm,
  gravity_value_t* args, uint32_t nargs, 
  uint32_t retIndex, void* data
) {
  int lhs, rhs, rt;

  // Unwrap
  lhs = VALUE_AS_INT(args[1]);
  rhs = VALUE_AS_INT(args[2]);

  // Perform call, capture return
  rt = add(lhs, rhs);

  // Forward the return
  gravity_vm_setslot(vm, VALUE_FROM_INT(rt), retIndex);
}
```

By using C++ (98) templating or C preprocessor magic, would there be a way to generate wrapper functions?

A very, very crunched example of the above wrapper function, would be this one:

```
static void gravity_wrap_add(
  gravity_vm* vm,
  gravity_value_t* args, uint32_t nargs, 
  uint32_t retIndex, void* data
) {
  gravity_vm_setslot(vm, 
   VALUE_FROM_INT(
     add(VALUE_AS_INT(args[1]), VALUE_AS_INT(args[2]))
   ), 
  retIndex);
}
```

This version is technically what I want to achieve - but through methods like the preprocessor or C++ templating. For cross-platform compatibility reasons, I'd like to stick with C++98 (since MSVC isn't exactly good on modern features).

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you are attempting, but if I understand, you could include `limits.h` and within `gravity_wrap_add` validate `INT_MIN <= args[1] && args[1] <= INT_MAX` (the same for `args[2]`) and then simply cast `(int)args[1]` and for `args[2]` -- presuming `gravity_value_t` is the same size as `int` on your system. If that's not what you are asking, update your question. (admittedly, I may be completely missing the point as I'm not familiar with gravity) That would be C89/C++98 compiant.

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty tedious without variadic templates, but you should be able to do a small number of arguments:

```
namespace gravity {
  template<class T> struct value {};
  // for brevity and deduction:
  template<class T> T get(const gravity_value_t &v)
  {return value<T>::get(v);}
  template<class T> gravity_value_t put(const T &t)
  {return value<T>::put(t);}
  template<> struct value<int> {
    int get(const gravity_value_t &v)
    {return VALUE_AS_INT(v);}
    gravity_value_t put(int i)
    {return VALUE_FROM_INT(i);}
  };
  // more specializations…

  template<class R,R f()>
  void wrap(gravity_vm* vm,
            gravity_value_t* args, uint32_t nargs, 
            uint32_t retIndex, void* data) {
    assert(nargs==0);
    gravity_vm_setslot(vm,put(f()),retIndex);
  }
  template<class R,class A,R f(A)>
  void wrap(gravity_vm* vm,
            gravity_value_t* args, uint32_t nargs, 
            uint32_t retIndex, void* data) {
    assert(nargs==1);
    gravity_vm_setslot(vm,put(f(get<A>(args[0]))),retIndex);
  }
  // more overloads with more arguments…

  /*gravity_register*/(wrap<int,int,int,add>);
}
```

As usual, `void` return types will be a pain; you have to repeat *each* argument-count overload for `R` of `void`.

It would be possible to use deduction to avoid repeating the signature when using `wrap`, but then you get fewer functions and  extra closure objects to distinguish them (which you can presumably use via the `data` argument).